# Get file path of an imported 2nd module inside a function which is in 3rd module while executing first module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am importing module `Y.py` in `X.py` and there is a function `my_func()` in module `Z.py` which I am importing in `Y.py` How can I print the path of `Y.py` in `my_func()` while executing `X.py` without passing any parameter to `my_func()`

Module X

```
# this is module X

import Y

#some code
```

Module Y

```
# this is module Y

from Z import *
my_func()

#some code
```

Module Z

```
# this is module Z

def my_func()
    print("the path of Y module is: ")  # here I want to print the path of Y.py

# do something with the path of Y.py
```

When I execute X.py it should print the path of Y.py, I tried using `os.getcwd()` but its giving me the path of X.py not the path of Y.py

Comment: Why do you think this is important?

Comment: You can use `inspect` to discern who imported you. Still, why do you need this?

Comment: You just wrapped my neurons all in a bunch oh boy that was confusing

Answer (score 2):

You use the [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) attribute of the module object:

```
import Y

def my_func():
    path = Y.__file__
```